Simulating event type and time-to-event from competing inhomogeneous Poisson processes
Suppose I have two independent Poisson processes with rates $\lambda_1(t)$ (for event type 1) and $\lambda_2(t)$ (for event type 2).
I want to simulate from this process. It seems intuitive that the following should work:

Simulate $\tau_1$, representing the time at which event type 1 would occur if assuming a survival model with cumulative hazard $\int_0^t\lambda_1(t')dt'$. (I could do this using adaptive thinning or numerically inverting the CDF.)
Do similarly to get $\tau_2$, representing the time at which event type 2 would occur.
Choose the event to be whichever happens first. I.e. if $\tau_1<\tau_2$ then event 1 happens; otherwise, event 2 happens.

I am struggling to find out if and why this is true. Any ideas are most welcome.
Note I could calculate the probability event 1 occurs by working out the probability:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau_1<\tau_2) = \int_0^{\inf} \int_0^{\tau_2} p(\tau_1,\tau_2) d\tau_1 d\tau_2\\ = \int_0^{\inf} p(\tau_2)\int_0^{\tau_2} p(\tau_1) d\tau_1 d\tau_2\\
= \int_0^{\inf} p(\tau_2) F_1(\tau_2) d\tau_2, 
$$
but I am struggling to get further than this.
Note 2 I am not sure whether an equivalent simulation process is:

simulate a time $\tau$ from a Poisson process with rate $\lambda_1(t)+\lambda_2(t)$
choose the event to be of type 1 with probability $\lambda_1(\tau)/ (\lambda_1(\tau)+\lambda_2(\tau))$; event 2, otherwise.

